# Get name of current function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

**Update**

How can I get function name which is currently being execute using `Kotlin`?

I'm trying to get the function name of the function which is currently being execute  as below but it's always coming as null

```
val funName = Object().`class`.enclosingMethod?.name;
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found one of the way:-

```
val name = object : Any() {

}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
```

Above code can also be refine as -

```
val name = object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
```

---

Edit because incorrect duplicate flag prevents a new answer:

A more Java way is this:

```
Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[1].methodName
```

but it takes ~47ms on my system compared with ~13ms for the object() based one: nearly 4 times slower.

Comment: to be safe:

object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod?.name

Comment: object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod worked in Kotlin 1.2.x, but seems to no longer work in Kotlin 1.3.50

Comment: The stackTrace method will not work on overriden methods. Try running that code in an Activity's onCreate and it will return a method called "getStackTrace". Running enclosingMethod in onCreate will also return null.

Comment: Can you get function argument values as well?

Comment: Use "Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[3].methodName" if you have a Log method and want the name of the parent method.

Comment: works on kotlin 1.6.10, so comment by @GreenSaguaro does not seem to apply (anymore)

Comment: Both approaches are tricky. There might not be a class for Kotlin functions defined at file level, and the thread stack deep might vary.

Answer (score 26):

There's also another option if you don't need the name to be discovered dynamically at runtime:

```
instance::method.name
```

Check below example on https://pl.kotl.in/1ZcxQP4b3:

```
fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    test.methodA()
    println("The name of method is ${test::methodA.name}")
}

class Test {
    fun methodA() {
        println("Executing method ${this::methodA.name}")
        println("Executing method ${::methodA.name} - without explicit this")
    }
}
```

After executing `main()` you will see:

```
Executing method methodA
Executing method methodA - without explicit this
The name of method is methodA
```

This way you can leverage all the "IDE intelligence" (renaming, searching for occurrences, etc.) but what's important, all occurrences of `instance::method.name` are replaced by Kotlin to ordinary strings during compilation. If you decompile Kotlin-generated bytecode, you'll see:

```
public final void main() {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.methodA();
    String var2 = "The name of method is " + "methodA"; // <--- ordinary string, no reflection etc.
    boolean var3 = false;
    System.out.println(var2);
}
```

Comment: more simply `::yourMethod.name` :)

Comment: @MustafaOzhan Not in Compose. "Function References of Composable functions are not currently supported".

Comment: @dominik This is not needed. Android Studio also can also rename all matches of the old method name inside comments and strings. Just bring up the options popup after the renaming caret appears.